# Center and scale factor predictors within train function from caret in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm having an issue with the preProc argument for the train function using the R caret package. I want to center and scale my predictors but ignore the factor columns. When I preProcess outside of train, it works fine but I'm hoping to pre-process within the train function. Am I missing something?

Below is an example where the factor predictor is ignored when using preProcess outside of train.

```
df <- data.frame(
    score = runif(1000, 80, 110),
    var1 = as.factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
    var2 = runif(1000, 5, 25)
)
preProcess(df[-1], method=c('center','scale'))

Created from 1000 samples and 2 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (1)
  - ignored (1)
  - scaled (1)
```

Here is what happens when I use preProc inside of train

```
df <- data.frame(
    score = runif(1000, 80, 110),
    var1 = as.factor(sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)),
    var2 = runif(1000, 5, 25)
)
mod <- train(score ~., data = df,
             method = "lm",
             preProc = c("center", "scale"))
mod$preProcess

Created from 1000 samples and 2 variables

Pre-processing:
  - centered (2)
  - ignored (0)
  - scaled (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call is dispatched to `train.formula` where your data is converted to a matrix with the expression `model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts)`.

Since your data are now in matrix form and matrices are atomic the values are coerced to the same type. In this instance `double`. This also has an odd side effect of renaming `var1` to `var11`, which you can see if you inspect the `mod$preProcess` output (e.g. `mod$preProcess$mean`). Not sure why that is the case, but I do not think  it is related to your question.

It appears the class information is captured before this matrix conversion and ultimately output in the results via the `ptype` element, but does nothing other than get output:

```r
sapply(mod$ptype, class)
     var1      var2 
 "factor" "numeric"
```

However, the model matrix is what gets passed to `train.default` which then goes on to run `preProcess()`. By the time that it reaches that step, the factor information is already stripped and that variable is of class `double`. As you noted `preProcess()` does a series of checks and only evaluates on numeric data (numeric in the sense that it is of class "integer", "numeric", or "double"). So when `preProcess()` is called via `train()` your values are already `double`, which is why they get scaled and centered.

However, the same conversion to a matrix is not made when you call `preProcess()` directly and so the factor class is caught and removed before scaling and centering.

From the `preProcess` argument documentation for `?train` it specifies:

> Pre-processing code is only designed to work when x is a simple matrix or data frame.

I *think* this is what they are getting at -- calling this argument is only for "simple" meaning all values are of the same class. If they are not of the same class they will ultimately be coerced.

---

Long story short, I think you ought to either pass the preprocessed data to `train()` or create a recipe and pass that to `train()` like so:

```r
library(recipe)
recipe(score ~ ., data = df) |>
  step_center(all_numeric_predictors()) |>
  step_scale(all_numeric_predictors()) |>
  train(method = "lm", data = df)
```

If you go the `recipe` route you should read the documentation carefully to see if factors are included in `all_numeric_predictors()`, I am not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! All of what you're saying makes sense, I appreciate you looking into this.